# Why Newtonsoft's serializer can create json, which wouldn't be able to deserialize?

Tags: c#, json.net

I've notice such strange thing. Why can such instance be serialized, instead of exception? Why do I get exception at the last command, the same option makes this json?

```
class Dto
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public List<string> Property { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dto =  new Dto
    {
        Property = null
    };

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto, settings);
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dto>(json, settings);
}
```

Comment: What is the exception? And I assume you have a typo on the 2nd argument on the last line - since you're using a capital `S` there but not on the line before

Comment: JsonSerializerException about trying deserialize null value.

Comment: If you want your List<string> to be nullable, you need to declare it as List<string>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fredrik's answer is not correct.
`[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` is applicable on both `Serialization` and `Deserialization`. If you want to ensure, try this code:

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public string Data { get; set; } = "default";
    }

    var originObj = new MyClass() {Id = 12, Data = null};
    var setting = new JsonSerializerSettings {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore};
    var jsn1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(originObj); //throws
```

Investigating the [`Newtonsoft` source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)  we can find that it is just implementation.

It allows you to skip `null` value if there is `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` on `Serialization` - Just open [JsonSerializerInternalWriter Implementation](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/6b9f467e817854532ea31e6c08abe47c53ac8b5c/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs) and find `CalculatePropertyValues` method (then find `ShouldWriteProperty` condition).

But it **ignores any settings and throws an exception** if Property is marked as `Required` - Find `EndProcessProperty` [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/6b9f467e817854532ea31e6c08abe47c53ac8b5c/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs).

Answer (score 3):

The `Required` option for `JsonPropertyAttribute` is only applicable for deserialization. See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyRequired.htm.

Thus when you ignore null values in the settings, which applies to both serialization and deserialization, you allow it to be omitted when serialized - which also means that there will be nothing there to deserialize, hence the exception.

Comment: Makes some sense, but it confuses a little. Probably they had some reasons for implementing it such we see.

Answer (score 0):

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dto>(json, Settings);`

Looks like a typo due to the capital `S` of `Settings` when it should be `settings`.